# Squish 7.0.1 is missing the startwinaut.exe binary

Tags: squish

The Squish binary `startwinaut.exe` appears to be missing from a clean installation.

I'm trying to start an AUT using Squish 7.0.1 and the `startApplication("msiexec /i \"C:\\myinstaller.msi\"")` Ruby function call. The call fails with an error `"An error occurred while starting the AUT."`

I checked to be sure that `msiexec` was a registered AUT, in the `C:\Windows\System32` directory, which it was.

Verbose logs showed that it was unable to find `C:\squish\bin\startwinaut.exe`. I can find [documentation on startwinaut](https://doc.qt.io/squish/cli-startaut.html#startwinaut), but I can't find the binary anywhere in the installation.

I was able to find an older 6.3.2 version of Squish, and it had the `startwinaut.exe` binary.

Where is startwinaut.exe in Squish 7? Do I need to procure an extension pack from somewhere, or somehow enable additional features in the installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various Squish editions. `startwinaut.exe` is only in "Squish for Windows" and "Squish for Java" (on Windows).

Comment: The downloads page had about 50 versions on it. After searching through it, I found the editions to which you refer, and they do indeed contain the `startwinaut.exe` binary.